# Sqlite query synax error

Tags: sqlite, spatialite

```
update room1f set nearestStaircase=‘POINT(-79.92094988409 43.25888417131)’ where locatoin=‘POINT(-79.9212601080121 43.2588970425146)’
```

I got error:

> near "43.25888417131": syntax error:

The nearestStaircase and location is just TEXT. I treat them as string. Could someone help me?

Comment: Remove the fancy-quotes (`‘’`) and use `'` if they are in your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

NVM,solved. I should use " rather than '

Comment: Just to be clear, from your question it does *not* appear that you used the character `'`, but rather the characters `‘` and `’`, which are quite different.  The single-tick character should work correctly (and is the SQL default string quotation character.  Did you write your code in a word processing program, by any chance?